# Unable to view my web api data directly from the browser of another machine

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have just started with my first api project. It runs successfully and shows me my data in xml format on the browser.The url on the browser says localhost:portno/api/employees

My question is: how can i access the same data by directly typing on the above url (localhost:portno/api/employees) from a browser on another machine?

Comment: You cannot with that exact URL. The other machine would need to use your machines IP address in place of localhost and you would need to have your firewall open to allow it.

Local host is just a shortcut to the local IP 127.0.0.1, do an ipconfig in command prompt to get your IP address and use that from the other machine.

Comment: also if you are running this from visual studio and are using IISExpress to host, it doesn't allow remote browsing automatically.  you would need to configure that.